# share the same php function if `all years` option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<select id='selYear'>
<option value='all'>ALL YEARS</option>
<option>2018</option>
<option>2019</option>
</select>

$('#selYear').on('change' function(){
    let a = $(this).val();
    $.post('articles-pro.php', {fn: 'sel_year', args: [a]}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**articles-pro.php**

```
function sel_year($a)
{ global $db;
    $sql = "select id, date from arts where date like :adate order by date desc";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([
        ":adate" => $a . "%"
    ]);

    ...rest of code
}
```

This works if user selects a year from `selYear` dropdown.

If `all` is selected - problem is because there is no such a value in `date` column.

Of course, I can write a separate function on php side, but it would be better to share the same function (`sel_year`).

How to do this?

Comment: why not if statement to say if a == all, select without a where?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I forgott `global $db`, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create an IF statement for if `$a == "all"`.

```
//default query
$sql = "SELECT id, date FROM arts WHERE date LIKE :adate ORDER BY date DESC";

//default params
$params = [":adate" => $a . "%"];

//check if input is "all"
if($a == "all") {

    //overwrite default query if $a == "all"
    $sql = "SELECT id, date FROM arts ORDER BY date DESC";

    //overwrite default params
    $params = [];
}

$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute($params);

//...rest of code
```

---

My shorter solution, inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204013/5827005 (Using [Ternaries](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary))

```
//set default values
$sql = 'SELECT id, date FROM arts WHERE date LIKE :adate ORDER BY date DESC';
$params = [':adate' => "$a%"];

//check if $a === 'all', if it is, change $sql and $params, if it's not, leave defaults
$sql = $a === 'all' ? 'SELECT id, date FROM arts ORDER BY date DESC' : $sql;
$params = $a === 'all' ? [] : $params;

$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute($params);
```

This solution is *shorter*, but honestly I don't think this matters as much as readability/maintainability, so I would probably still use the first solution. I also doubt you'll see much if any performance difference in these, but if I had to guess, the first solution may be *slightly* more efficient because you don't have to check if `$a == "all"` multiple times, and I'm not sure if ternaries are more efficient or not.

Comment: you can better this by adding the select (as it's the same both cases) and if $a !== 'all', concat the where

Comment: @treyBake Idk, that seems like it would be less verbose and harder to maintain

Comment: Hmm.. maybe.. I think I just prefer the fewest lines possible, in fact I'll add an answer and I'll demonstrate my means :)

Comment: @treyBake I would be interested in seeing how it would be less lines, I think my solution is already very short :)

Comment: Maybe I'm cheating a little using ternary ;) haha

Comment: @treyBake Yeah I was considering using a ternary, but I wanted to avoid checking if $a was equal to "all" multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of `$a` in your function:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `date` FROM `arts` '; # select is the same either case
$orderBy = 'ORDER BY `date` DESC;'; # as is order by
$where = ($a === 'all' ? 'WHERE `date` LIKE :adate' : ''); # ternary to see if we need a where
$params = ($a === 'all' ? [] : [':adate' => $a. '%']); # same applies to params

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql. $where .$orderBy); # and exec
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: note: I'll be afk but will review when home^^ if bad, will delete :p

Comment: This is probably something I would do if I was more worried about just short code, and didn't care about maintainability. In this case, maintainability may not be a huge burden, since it's such a simple function anyways, but I still prefer my code to be a bit cleaner than this (especially since mine is only 2 lines longer), I also hate doing multiple checks for the same clause. Good answer though!

Comment: That said, I updated my answer with a version that matches the length requirement of yours, but I believe is also more readable :)

Comment: Also, `[':adate' => $a]` should be `[':adate' => "$a%"]` (based on OP's code)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton haha  some valid points, I upvoted your edit, some good lookin' code and you're right! will amend my params :)

Answer (score 0):

You could either write an if statement in the function `sel_year` which checks the value of `$a`. If that value is `all` you can give the `$db->prepare` a separate SQL string without checking for the date, effectively returning all dates.